# Make unable to find rule

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

Perhaps I missing something, but this make file fails, with error (paraphrasing due to localization is active):

```
there is no rule to build target ****.o
```

where **** is the name of existing .cpp file. Make version 3.81, gcc 4.7.5 (if that's relevant).

Here is the makefile.

```
program_name := librlsmatt.a
source_dirs  :=   ../src    
include_dirs := $(source_dirs)

CXX = g++
AR = ar 

WARNS := -Wall -Wno-deprecated -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-parameter
CFLAGS:= $(addprefix -I, $(include_dirs)) $(WARNS) -fstack-protector-all -g 
ARFLAGS := cru

source_files := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.cpp, $(source_dirs) ) )
object_files := $(notdir $(source_files:.cpp=.o) )
dep_files := $(object_files:%.o=%.d)

.PHONY :  clean

-include $(dep_files)

$(program_name): $(object_files)
    $(info Linking ...)
    @$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(object_files)

%.o: %.cpp makefile
    $(info Compiling $< ...)
    @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -MF $(@:%.o=%.d) -MT $@

clean:
    $(info Clean $(program_name)...)
    @$(RM) -f $(program_name) $(object_files) $(dep_files)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that the default target in a Makefile is the first one; therefore if we the dependency files exist, and we include them before the main target, then the `.o` target in the first included dependency rule will be the default target. As a rule of thumb, include dependencies somewhere farther down, like the very end.

The pattern matching problem in this Makefile is caused by the fact that the `.o` files do not have a directory prefix, due to the use of `$(notdir ...)` in the expansion which generates them, but the `.cpp` files do.

`make` is trying to build some `foo.o` and the `%.o: %.cpp` rule tells it to look for `foo.cpp`. But there is no `foo.cpp`; what exists is is some `src/dir/foo.cpp`.

If you really want the `.o` files to be in one directory, the `VPATH` mechanism may be a possibility.  If `src/dir` is in the `VPATH`, then when `make` looks for `foo.cpp` to update `foo.o`, it will find it in `src/dir`.

If you force all `.o` files from the tree into one directory, you have to be sure there are no two `.cpp` files with the same name.

If you want to deposit `.o` files outside of the source tree (which is useful, because you can then have a read-only source tree, for instance), it's probably best to mirror the structure of the source tree in the output tree, like this:

```
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp:   # where the % stem is src/dir/whatever/foo
```

The idea is that the object file is `$(OUTPUT_DIR)/src/whatever/foo.o`, and the source file is `src/whatever/foo.cpp`.

The recipe has to make sure that the directory `$(OUTPUT_DIR)/src/whatever` exists; so a `mkdir -p` command will be needed in there somewhere:

```
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp:
        $(info Compiling $< ...)
        @mkdir -p $(dir $@) 
        @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -MF $(@:%.o=%.d) -MT $@
```

Comment: Ah... that's what I get from hastily writing a small version of big makefile at 3am. I actually know how to make "mirroring tree" in target directory, but skipped the writing. There is no subdirs in this project, but there could be. Thanks pointing out the VPATH trick and that I misplaced include, that's was the reason in this case

Comment: @Swift - It does not help that make has nearly no useful debugging facilities. The make folks think `$(info ...)` is the pinnacle of debugging.

Comment: @jww I use debug/dryrun modes and dumps make provides, but it's not always clear what I'm missing in case like this, espevially when only access to target I have is through wingdb or similar.